# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commands')

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is the part of the main file that I think is causing the issue

```
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}
```

This is the code in the Interaction Create script where the error is coming from

```
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return;

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    },
};
```

Forgot to mention the error is on the line defining 'command' in the interaction create script

FULL ERROR:

```
const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commands')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\New Bot\events\interactionCreate.js:6:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\New Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:70:12)
:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\New Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\New Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\New Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\New Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message?

Comment: ```
const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commands')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\New Bot\events\interactionCreate.js:6:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Desktop\New Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:70:12)
:4:36)
```
cant add anymore because it goes over the character limit

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting a comment.

Comment: Where is `client` coming from in your Interaction Create script?

Comment: as an argument from a function in a module.exports

Answer (score 3):

As per the [discord.js documentation](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#individual-event-files):

> In most cases, you can access your `client` instance in other files by
> obtaining it from one of the other discord.js structures, e.g.
> `interaction.client` in the `interactionCreate` event.

Change:

```
const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
```

to:

```
const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```js
client.commands = new Collection();
```

to:

```js
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
```

Comment: i was extracting Collection from the discord.js package so tried just defining the discord.js package by itself and putting Discord.Collection(), same error

Answer (score -2):

You have not defined the client

This is how you should start writing your bot:

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login("yourBotToken");
```

> [source](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file)

Comment: That would throw an error in the "main" file first.

Comment: He definitely has a problem with the client definition

Comment: If client wasn't defined then the definition for `client.commands` would of also thrown an error. Client is defined, the error states that `.commands` is the undefined value

Comment: yea i have client defined exactly like that in my main file and it is being defined as an argument already